# Query para multiples columnas de un mismo campo

Tags: mysql, sql

beunas tengo una consulta con el siguiente query de mysql he querido traer todas las notas de las distintas tareas de unos estudiantes que cada tarea con una columna y debajo las notas de esa tarea lo unicom que he conseguido esque en una columna todos los nombres de tareas revueltas con otra columna con las notas y quiero cada tarea en una columna. entonces cree un query que me manda el siguiente error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

el query en cuestion es

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.username AS cedula,
    u.firstname AS nombre,
    u.lastname AS apellido,
    u.email AS correo,
    c.fullname,
    c.shortname,
IF
    (
        gi.itemname = 'Trabajo Individual#2',
        '0',
        (
        SELECT
        IF
            ( gg.finalgrade IS NULL, '0', ROUND( gg.finalgrade / gg.rawgrademax * 100, 2 ) ) AS porcentaje 
        FROM
            mdl_course AS c
            JOIN mdl_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
            JOIN mdl_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
            JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
            JOIN mdl_grade_grades AS gg ON gg.userid = u.id
            JOIN mdl_grade_items AS gi ON gi.id = gg.itemid 
        WHERE
            c.shortname = '001-IA-42-19-03-G1' 
            AND gi.courseid = c.id 
            AND gi.itemname = 'Trabajo Individual#2' 
        GROUP BY
            u.username 
        ) 
    ) AS porcentaje1,
    FROM_UNIXTIME( gi.timemodified ) TimeModified 
FROM
    mdl_course AS c
    JOIN mdl_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
    JOIN mdl_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
    JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
    JOIN mdl_grade_grades AS gg ON gg.userid = u.id
    JOIN mdl_grade_items AS gi ON gi.id = gg.itemid
    JOIN mdl_course_categories AS cc ON cc.id = c.category 
WHERE
    c.shortname = "001-IA-42-19-03-G1" 
    AND gi.courseid = c.id 
GROUP BY
    u.username
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar

Answer (score 0):

El error parte de que la sub-consulta que tienes te retorna más de un registro, donde debes poner atención es en:

```
SELECT
IF ( gg.finalgrade IS NULL, '0', ROUND( gg.finalgrade / gg.rawgrademax * 100, 2 ) ) AS porcentaje 
FROM
mdl_course AS c
JOIN mdl_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
JOIN mdl_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
JOIN mdl_grade_grades AS gg ON gg.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_grade_items AS gi ON gi.id = gg.itemid 
WHERE
c.shortname = '001-IA-42-19-03-G1' 
AND gi.courseid = c.id 
AND gi.itemname = 'Trabajo Individual#2' 
GROUP BY
u.username
```

y ver que te muestra la consulta, solo debería mostrar un registro si quieres que funcione como esperas.

Como no puedo ver la estructura de tus tablas ni los registros es en lo único que podría ayudarte, si subes más información acerca de estructura y registros podría editar ésta respuesta. ;) Saludos